# admin session user edit posts

Tags: session, admin

In database I have a column `acc_type` as `int`, and I'm trying to code this if $_SESSION['accountTpye']==1 then allowed this user to edit the other users posts,

And should I use and instead of && ? " or , || ".

Example code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['username']==$dnn2['author'] || $_SESSION['accc_type']==1['username'])) {
    echo "<a href='edit.php'>Edit</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']==$dnn2['author']) || $_SESSION['acc_type']==1){
    echo "<a href='edit.php'>Edit</a>";
}
```

This part doesn't make sense:

```
$_SESSION['acc_type']==1['username']
```

If you just remove that last ['username'] and then wrap the session username part to be the first part of the conditional so the acc_type one does not depend on it then things should be ok

UPDATE:

In your login.php file locate this part:

```
$req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
$dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
if($dn['password']==sha1($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
{
     $form = false;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
     $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
```

You need to also select the acc_type. ASSUMING it's a field in the users table, modify the query to read this:

```
'select password,id, acc_type from users where username="'.$username.'"'
```

Then make sure to set the session var:

```
     $form = false;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
     $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
     $_SESSION['acc_type'] = $dn['acc_type'];
```

When you test this, make sure you log out then log bacak in again.

Comment: i tryed that code before and it didn't work, but if i do it in this way: $_SESSION['username']==$admin it works fine, becasue i have this code $admin=

Comment: Are you not setting $_SESSION['acc_type']? We have no way of knowing what $admin is, so verifying that for you would require you updating your question with more details. My example is logical and would work if the unknown vars are actually set as expected.

Comment: I meant, if i do it in this way: $_SESSION['username']==$admin it works fine, becasue i have this code $admin="admin", but this is not helping becasue it checks if the session user is admin.

Comment: have you tried var_dump($_SESSION)? Like I said, are you positive $_SESSION['acc_type'] is set AND is 1?

Comment: i don't know about var_dump, and yes im sure that acc_type is 1, 0 is member, if its 1 admin, if its 2 mod

Comment: so what are the results of var_dump($_SESSION). you can do that just above the conditional

Comment: i get this: array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["userid"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Well there it is. You're not setting acc_type. Check your login script and make sure it's being set on login, or default to 0 if not

Comment: you want me to set acc_type as a login session instead of session['username'] ?.  your first code works but its wired, when i set it to acc_type==1 it allowing the other username with acc_type 2 to edit acc_type==1 post.

Comment: facepalm... not instead of. In addition to. You can set anything you want in a session var. According to the code YOU provided, you are supposed to be setting BOTH username and acc_type.

Comment: lol sorry i'm not good at php, i added this 2 line of code in login.php, if(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['acc_type'])) ---- $_SESSION['acc_type'] = $dn['acc_type']; ---- please tell me how to ?

Comment: you need to update your question with the contents of login.php. We can't continue in comments and make sense

Comment: You need to click the edit button on your question. share | edit | close | flag . Then copy and paste your login.php code. I MUST see the code to help. No other way to do it

Comment: Not quite what I mean. You need to paste the ENTIRE login.php code. Not just what you recently added. I need to see what the code is doing when the login form is submitted

Comment: lol say it like that, its a long code so i post it here: http://pastebin.com/NZKqCW9h

Comment: First IS there a acc_type field in the users table? Did you do any testing to make sure the session vars are being set at all? Did you log out and log back in? You have to understand most of us answering questions have been doing this for years and years so responses like "didn't work" are not only ridiculous, but also tell us we're working with someone who may not fundamentally know what they're doing. What you're ultimately asking for is like php 101. First thing you learn. It is not complex at all, so the provided solutions ARE correct. How the solution is applied seems to be the real issue

Comment: yes acc_type is in users filed otherwise the other codes won't work, and also checked, and yes tested the vars are being set, and yes i did  log out and log back in more than 1 time as you said it before, and sorry i'm a new user first time using this site to just get a help, was working on this for a week and couldn't find any silutions. i found that one thing will work, if session username is equal to admin, means if the db username is == to admin then do something, but this is not helpful

Comment: then that means $_SESSION['acc_type'] is not == 1. That conditional says specifically that. You can try identical $_SESSION['acc_type'] === 1 or alternatively setting acc_type to a string "admin", "editor", "user" and comparing against that. One way or the other, you code was definitely NOT setting $_SESSION['acc_type'] before, so saying "not helpful" is a matter of perspective. username == admin, however, is certainly not a solution as you know. But given the conditional works with that, it means the second comparison is not ever being met.

Comment: by helpful i meant its not usefull if i use username == admin, what if the admin changed there username ?. i'm conused

Comment: It just occurred to me - if acc_type is a varchar or some other string based data type in the database, then the comparison operator should also be a string. So $_SESSION['acc_type']== "1" would be correct if that's the case. Notice the quotes. Although, in the database, acc_type should be a tiny int 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will resolve your problem :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']){

  if( ($_SESSION['username']==$dnn2['author']) || ($_SESSION['acc_type']==1)  ){
      echo "<a href='edit.php'>Edit</a>";
   }
```

}